# Delete last row in a table android

Tags: android, row, delete-row

My question is quite straightforward. I have a table, with, lets say x rows, with each an id, but I don't know how many rows I have. Now I want to delete the last row of my table for some reason... Is there an easy way to do that in android? I have been trying to use the last_insert_rowid  in my where clause...but no luck so far...
Any idea to do that with the sqlite database tools of android?

Comment: are you talking about a table layout or a database table?

Comment: Are you taking about a database table, HTML table or a TableLayout?

Comment: ups sorry, that was claer in my head. database, sqlite database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that last_insert_rowid means that you are talking about db.

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test);
```